# If I install BIDS,does SSIS engine (run time) gets install?

Tags: ssis, bids

I have installed Buisness Inteligence Studio, does this mean my machine has ssis engine installed? I just drove analogy from the fact that if I install Visual Studio then .Net framework gets installed by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not exactly. BIDS is a plug-ig for Visual Studio that allows you to build BI solutions (SSIS, SSAS and SSRS). You conld have BIDS installed because you have a Reporting Service intance installed for example.

Usually if you have Integration Services or an instance of SSAS or SSRS intalled, you would have BIDS too. But that not mandatory, It wouldnt be true on a PROD server for example where you can have SSIS but wouldnt have BIDS.

Best way yo know if you have SSIS is to go to the "SQL Server Configuration Manager". It will list all instances of the 3 products you have intalled